# video no funciona en safari ni en pc con windows

Tags: javascript, html, modal, video

He puesto un video con `html` y `javascript` pero en mi ordenador apple y otros apple funciona, pero en un pc con sistema windows o bien desde safari en mac no funciona el modal con el video. Alguna idea??

**Con esto abro el video:**

```
<button type="button" class="btnVerpromocion video-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-src="video/cesar2.mp4" data-target="#myModal" id="paraForm">
   <i class="fas fa-video"></i> MIRA COMO
</button>
```

**El modal con el video**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg corrigeModal21" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content modal-contentCorrige" style="background: inherit;">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close close2121" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video" allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**El JavaScript para que cargue el video**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Gets the video src from the data-src on each button
  var $videoSrc;
  $('.video-btn').click(function() {
    $videoSrc = $(this).data("src");
  });
  //console.log($videoSrc);

  // when the modal is opened autoplay it
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {

    // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. Youtube related video is like a box of chocolates... you never know what you're gonna get
    $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0");
  })
  // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
  $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
    // a poor man's stop video
    //$("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc);
    location.reload();
  })
  // document ready
});
```

Comment: porque usas iframe para cargar el vídeo? no puedes usar el tag `video` de html5?

Comment: por que con el tag `video` el javascript no me funcionaba @hawks

Comment: y exactamente que error te daba el tag video?

Comment: mmm no lo recuerdo, al cambiar el iframe con la etiqueta `video` no me funcionaba el javascript

Comment: puedes probar `<iframe allow="autoplay" />`?

Comment: pero el problema no es ese, es que el video en algunos navegadores o sistemas operativos con windows no lo reproduce

Comment: sin mas datos mucho no puedo aportar. Te sale algun error en la consola?